# OS X: How to get Reminders.app to stop asking for permission to determine your location

Tags: macos, reminders, geolocation

Every time I add a location-based reminder to Reminders on iOS, the Reminders.app on OS X asks for permission to obtain my location. Is there any way to get OS X to permanently give permission to Reminders.app to obtain my location? Since I *want* to use Reminders.app this way it is unnecessary for it to ask every time.

Comment: Have you tried repairing your drive permissions or booting to recovery and resetting your user folder permissions? It may be that some permissions are not allowing OS X to save your preference for location services.

Comment: What I think is happening is that I give it permission and it then doesn't ask for a period of time, but after a while, say after the reminder is completed, and I create a new location-based reminder then it asks for permission again.

Comment: That is a good possibility, but it should save the preference regardless of whether the reminder was completed or not (at least, in my humble UX opinion). Give the permissions repair a shot, it won't cause any harm, unless you have ACLs set up, in which case you'll have to set them up again.

Comment: I am not on my computer now. But I can guess that you could change the `com.apple.reminders.plist` file located in `~/Preferences` to have permissions. Sorry for it being a rough guess... As I said, I ain't on my compiter now

Comment: @TheBro21 Reminders is now sandboxed, so the preferences are stored in: `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.reminders` and possibly  `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.RemindersNC`. However, I haven't found any relevant data in those directories.